# Limit on number of records per page in Cassandra pagination

Tags: cassandra, pagination, spring-data-cassandra

I am using CassandraPageRequest for fetching data based on page size.

Here is my code:

```
    public CassandraPage<CustomerEntity> getCustomer(int limit, String pagingState)
    {
        final CassandraPageRequest cassandraPageRequest = createCassandraPageRequest(limit, pagingState);
        return getPageOfCustomer(cassandraPageRequest);
    }

    private CassandraPage<CustomerEntity> getPageOfCustomer(final CassandraPageRequest cassandraPageRequest) {
        final Slice<CustomerEntity> recordSlice = CustomerPaginationRepository.findAll(cassandraPageRequest);
        return new CassandraPage<>(recordSlice);
    }

    private CassandraPageRequest createCassandraPageRequest(final Integer limit, final String pagingState) {
        final PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, limit);
        final PagingState pageState = pagingState != null ? PagingState.fromString(pagingState) : null;
        return CassandraPageRequest.of(pageRequest, pageState);
    }
```

This works fine. However I want to know the recommendations on the "number of records per page". When I give 1000 as limit, it works fine. Suggest whether we can give 10000 or more than that for limit.

Answer (score 2):

I work at ScyllaDB - Scylla is a Cassandra compatible database.

I ran an experiment a few years back on the effect of page size and row size on cassandra paging.

What I have found is that the total amount of information that needs to be returned in bytes is the item that really matters. If you have very large rows - even 1000 maybe to much, if you have small rows 10000 should be ok.

[image: C* 3.11.0: does the default page_size make sense]

Other factor that should be considered are:

- Amount of tombstones in your data - tombstones have to be read and skipped in a query searching for live data having many of them will cause cassandra (and scylla) more work in search of the next live row.
- Type of query are you doing a range scan over multiple partitions or a single partition - a scan over multiple partitions maybe harder to fill data (especially in the case of alot of tombstones).
- Timeout - by increasing the page size - cassandra will have to search for more rows, if the read timeout / range scan timeout values are low the query may timeout.

Please note that Scylla has removed the need for its users to optimize the page size - it will cap your queries to 1MB of data / page size of rows.

You can find the complete slide deck / session searching for "Planning your queries for maximum performance" its old but still holds (in Scylla we have more optimizations :) ).